# Running Shell-scripts phase of build takes forever

Tags: xcode, shell, build, cocoapods

I am spending almost 30 seconds in running "2 of 3 shell-scripts" every time I build my project in Xcode.  I have a decent sized podfile with 20+ pods but beyond that, I'm not sure what causes this build phase to take so long, nor if I can avoid it.

Here is a picture of my build-phases.

[image]

Surely, it can cache whatever operations the shell-scripts are performing.  If I simply change one print statement to print "this" to "that", I shouldn't need to spend 30 seconds waiting for the scripts to run.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running latest version of coca pods . I was having similar issues i did the following:
1. First Quit Xcode from finder Menu
2. then updated the pod : `pod update` 
3. After that `pod install`